# It is possible to get an arraylist on the webmethod parameter from ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, arraylist

I create for my web application in C# webforms a webmethod which is invoked by an Ajax call.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string DataExport(ArrayList arr)
    {

    }
```

How I can fill the ArrayList of my method DataExport from the "data" field of the ajax call ?

Now my Ajax is simple like that :

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: "Default.aspx/DataExport",
                data: '{ arr:"' + test + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { },
                error: function (response) { }
            });
```

And test in the data field is JSON.I make several tests, and it works if I replace ArrayList by string and I get a string with the JSON inline.

Have you an idea how to modify the data to fill the type ArrayList of the webmethod ?

Comment: Your data `{arr: "test"}` is a [json](http://www.json.org/) **object**. I can imagine that your plan only works if your data comes as an json **array**, e.g. `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`

Comment: @RicoHerlt my datas are like that : [{"test1" : "test11"},{"test2 ": "test22"},{"test3" : "test33"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accept the JSON object as string in your web method then apply the necessary deserialization using the generic JsonConvert.DeserializeObject methods?

```
var test = JSON.stringify(valuesToBePassed);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "Default.aspx/DataExport",
            data: test,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) { },
            error: function (response) { }
        });
```

Then use the following snippet to extract the object in your Web Method:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObjectType>>(json);
```

Replacing `list` with a `List<MyObjectType>`. Or.. if you do not wish to create a model from the object, you could use the following:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you're posting to the server is not an array, it's an object with a single property `arr`. That property arr might be an array... we can't tell from your snippet.

The WebMethod you've implemented should support JSON deserialization, but you need the posted JSON and the WebMethod parameter type to line up.

- Create an object that represents one item in your list (e.g. `Person`)
- Switch from `ArrayList` to `List<T>` (e.g. `List<Person>`)
- Update your javascript to POST an array of `Person` objects

For the sake of getting from here to there, I'd recommend first writing the code to accept a single instance, then extend the code to accept a collection and post a javascript array `[]`.

```
public class Person {  public string Name { get; set; } }
public void DataExport(Person item) {

}

var postData =  '{ "Name": "Some Person" }';
$.ajax(url, postData);
```